# [Bot Framework][Skype for Business] How can I set a bot's icon picture in a chat window?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

How can I set a profile pic of a bot in a chat Window of Skype for Business with Bot Framework?

I've uploaded a custom icon from the bot's setting page. But it doesn't appear in a chat window.

Please refer to the attached screenshot.

[Chat Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiLZU.png)

Comment: Does the image appear at all in S4B? Like in the contacts list or anywhere else?  Or does it just not show up anywhere after you uploaded it?

Comment: So far, the image I set from the bot's setting page doesn't appear anywhere in S4B.

I want to set a profile pic of the of a bot like a human user and I want to know how.

Comment: I seems that we need an "Exchange Online" license to set a profile image of a bot on Skype for Business.

This is a message I saw when I tried to set a profile image for a bot from the setting page of Office 365.

"Change photo - You can’t upload a photo for this user because they don’t have a mailbox. Only internal users who have an Exchange Online license assigned can display a photo."

Comment: We've purchased an Exchange Online license and assigned it to a bot account. But we still see the same message and still can't upload a profile photo to a bot. :(
Does any one have any solution for this problem please?

Comment: A few days after I purchased an "Exchange Online" license for the bot, I was able to set a picture of the bot.Thank you very much for your support here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purchased an "Exchange Online" license for the bot.

After a few days, I was able to set a picture of the bot from Office 365 setting page.